# Getting wrong page numbers in TOC via docx4j-export-fo

Tags: docx4j

I'm using `docxj4` for generating Word documents and now I need to generate a table of contents. Since 3.3.0 version `docx4j` uses plutext conversion service to get page numbers that is inappropriate for me, so I need to use `docx4j-export-fo` library for that purpose. But it produces the wrong numbering... Seems like it gets the wrong page size or something like this, because all page numbers are lag 1-2 numbers. 
I've researched the source code and properties docx4j provides, but for now I didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, the standalone PDF Converter (which you can download from https://converter-eval.plutext.com/ ) exists precisely to provide better accuracy than can be expected from docx4j-export-fo.

export-fo uses XSL FO to layout the document, and because the XSL FO layout model is not a precise match for Word's, there are limits to what can be achieved.

That said, improvements may be possible in individual cases.  You'd need to share your docx somewhere for specific feedback.

Comment: Thank you for a feedback, but as for NDA purpose, I can't place my document here. There just about 3 paragraphs about 0.5-1 pagec each, with a plain text. How are you going to improve page numeration?)

Comment: I've replaced all sensitive text keeping original document structure and uploaded it here https://www.dropbox.com/s/yuk4swlnb2c152v/example.docx?dl=0 (File preview shows the correct page numbering somehow, but if you open it, you'll see that second TOC entry has page number 2 instead of 3).